# org.openapitools.generator.gradle.plugin.tasks.GenerateTask' property 'inputSpec' doesn't have a configured value

Tags: kotlin, gradle

I tried to generate two swagger yaml files in one build script

Here is my code

```
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm")
    id("org.openapi.generator")
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        java.srcDir("$buildDir/generate-resources/main/src/main/kotlin")
    }
}

dependencies {
    val jacksonVersion: String by project

    implementation(kotlin("stdlib"))
    testImplementation(kotlin("test-junit"))

    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:$jacksonVersion")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:$jacksonVersion")

}

    val dir = File("$rootDir/transport/spec/".toString())

    val swaggerList: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()

    dir.walkTopDown().forEach {
        val endsWith = it.name.endsWith(".yaml")
        if (endsWith) {
            swaggerList.add(it.name)
        }
    }
    swaggerList.forEach {swaggerItem->
        println(swaggerItem)
        val apiName = swaggerItem.replace(".yaml", "")

        tasks.create(
            "openApiGenerate" + apiName.capitalize(),
            org.openapitools.generator.gradle.plugin.tasks.GenerateTask::class)
            {

            val openapiGroup = "${rootProject.group}.openapi"
            generatorName.set("kotlin")
            packageName.set(openapiGroup)
            apiPackage.set("$openapiGroup.api")
            modelPackage.set("$openapiGroup.models")
            invokerPackage.set("$openapiGroup.invoker")
            inputSpec.set("$rootDir/transport/spec/$swaggerItem")
            println("setup input spec")

            globalProperties.apply {

                put("models", "")
                put("modelDocs", "false")
            }

            configOptions.set(
                mapOf(
                    "dateLibrary" to "string",
                    "enumPropertyNaming" to "UPPERCASE",
                    "serializationLibrary" to "jackson",
                    "collectionType" to "list"
                )
            )
        }
    }

tasks {
    compileKotlin {
        dependsOn(openApiGenerate)
    }
}
```

I launched this code via gradle build, but nothing works

I got this error

- In plugin 'org.openapi.generator' type 'org.openapitools.generator.gradle.plugin.tasks.GenerateTask' property 'inputSpec' doesn't have a configured value.

  Reason: This property isn't marked as optional and no value has been configured.

  Possible solutions:

  1. Assign a value to 'inputSpec'.
  2. Mark property 'inputSpec' as optional.

I tried to assign this property in different ways it was unsuccessful

how I can fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

In your `build.gradle` you are creating multiple tasks for each item in `swaggerList`. Each task is named: `"openApiGenerate" + apiName.capitalize()`. So when you call your build like this:

```
gradle openapiGenerate
```

it tries to use a default task configured with this name and not any of the ones you are creating.

Can you try to run it:

```
gradle openapiGenerateYOUR_API_NAME
```

and check what's the result?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the same error message was caused by having a `compileJava.dependsOn tasks.openApiGenerate` in the wrong `build.gradle` file.